# the usefulness of Azure FWs

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to know the usefulness of Azure FWs, knowing that any collaborator will have to connect to the VPN beforehand to access the cloud, Azure FW in this case it will be mandatory ?

Answer (score 0):

If the question you are asking is "*do I need to setup Azure FW in order to setup a VPN to an Azure VNET?*", then the answer is **no you don't have to**.

Azure FW allows you to perform both east-west and north-south traffic inspection.

> "East-West" traffic refers to traffic within a data center -- i.e.
> server to server traffic.
>
> "North-South" traffic is client to server
> traffic, between the data center and the rest of the network (anything
> outside the data center).

You can read more about Azure FW [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/overview).